# Need a unique, reversible function to convert text to integers in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to convert arbitrary alphanumeric IDs to integers that will be guaranteed to be unique and reversible.  Any cool tricks out there to do this?  I've looked at some hash functions and the like but usually they don't produce integer output or they are non-unique.

For example, suppose I have an ID such as AX36543TXQ.  I need a function that will uniquely map this into an integer in such a way that it will not collide with any other possible IDs and can be converted back to its alphanumeric form if need be.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0):

Avoid collision is very difficult, but you can do something similar, like this:

First: Creating a table with a column VARCHAR as Primary Key:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `pkey` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` TEXT NULL,
  `others` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pkey`));
```

Adding some data:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`pkey`, `name`, `others`) VALUES ('a', 'Albert', '123');
INSERT INTO `table` (`pkey`, `name`, `others`) VALUES ('b', 'Bernard', '456');
INSERT INTO `table` (`pkey`, `name`, `others`) VALUES ('c', 'Chelsea', '789');
```

As you can see, the column PKEY is the primary key, and VARCHAR:

```
DESCRIBE `table`;
```

Now, changing the Primary Key to another column based on Auto Increment:

1º) Create the column:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD COLUMN `new_key` INT;
```

2º) Fill the columns with a sequence of integers

```
SET @i=0;
SET @Count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`);
UPDATE `table` SET `new_key` = @Count-(@i:=@i+1)+1;
```

3º) Change the new column to be the Primary Key

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`new_key`);
ALTER TABLE SO1 MODIFY COLUMN ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

To see the final result:

```
DESCRIBE `table`;
```

And, you will have your original "primary key" to check, and the new Primary Key with unique integers for each row.

And to work in your case, the "function" will be:

```
select `new_key` from `table` where `pkey` = 'AX36543TXQ';
```

Assuming the result of the select above being '17', your "reverse function" will be:

```
select `new_pkey` from `table` where `new_key` = 17;
```